# How to cast float to string with no exponents in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have float data in a BigQuery table like 5302014.2 and 5102014.4.

I'd like to run a BigQuery SQL that returns the values in String format, but the following SQL yields this result:

```
select a, string(a) from my_table

5302014.2    "5.30201e+06"
5102014.4    "5.10201e+06"
```

How can I rewrite my SQL to return:

```
5302014.2    "5302014.2"
5102014.4    "5102014.4"
```

Answer (score 4):

use standardSQL doesn't have the problem

```
$ bq query '#standardSQL
SELECT a, CAST(a AS STRING) AS a_str FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[530201111114.2, 5302014.4]) a'
+-------------------+----------------+
|         a         |     a_str      |
+-------------------+----------------+
|         5302014.4 | 5302014.4      |
| 5.302011111142E11 | 530201111114.2 |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT STRING(INTEGER(f)) + '.' + SUBSTR(STRING(f-INTEGER(f)), 3)
FROM (SELECT 5302014.5642 f)
```

(not a nice hack, but a better method would be a great feature request to post at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3DFeature-Request)

Answer (score 1):

Converting your legacy sql to standard sql is really the best way going forward as far as working with GBQ is concerned. Standard sql is much faster and have way better implementation of features.

For your use case, going with standard sql with CAST(a AS STRING) would be best.